# How to get sibling controls of an Angular 6 AbstractControl in a nested Form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm am trying to figure out as to how to get the sibling controls of an AbstractControl/FormControl in a nested angular reactive form.

My situation is, I am trying to compare the value of 2 form controls, that are nested within, FormGroup>FormArray>FormGroup>FormArray>FormGroup

I am using a custom validator to ensure that, within the deepest level FormGroup, one FormControl value is greater than another other FormControl value, but I am unable to retrieve sibling FormControls.

I have passed in the other control name as a string to the custom validator:

```
static IsGreaterThan(GreaterThanControlName: string) : ValidatorFn | null {
    return (control: AbstractControl) : { [key: string]: any } => {

        const x = control.parent;
        const y = x.get(GreaterThanControlName);
        ...
    }
}
```

The idea is simple, I'm calling control.parent to get the parent FormGroup, and then using .get(GreaterThanControlName) to get the control of the FormGroup I am looking for.

When I only include:

```
const x = control.parent
```

A formgroup is retrieved and displayed (when written to the console), as expected.

However, if I then include:

```
const y = x.get(GreaterThanControlName);
```

or

```
const y = x.controls;
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

control.parent is now considered undefined, whereas previously it returned a FormGroup and the only difference is that I'm trying to retrieve one or more controls from the parent FormGroup of the original Control.

I could potentially use .root() however, the requirement to go through multiple FormGroups and FormArrays would be a cumbersome solution to the problem.

So how should I go about retrieving Sibling FormControls within a deeply nested form?

Any advice as to how to solve this, or improve my understanding of angular is greatly appreciated.

If any more code is required to describe the situation, please feel free to ask